# HTML URL button with variables

Tags: php, html, button

I really need some help. As you can see under in the code, I have a receiver, sender and a message for my site. When I click the button on the page it enters the page and sends the message to the receiver I enter in the URL. So what I want it to do: I want it to get the receiver, sender and message from the form into my URL. I have tried with PHP variables and JavaScript variables, but I can't get it to work.

```
<form>

Reciever: <input type="text" name="rcv" /><br><br>

Sender: <input type="text" name="snd" /><br><br>

Message: <input type="text" name="msg" /><br><br>
</form>


<div>
   <a id="mybutton" href="http://example.com/http4sms/send.asp?USER=Steffen&PW=steffen123&RCV=4782123254&TXT=hello&SND=Steffen" title="link to example.com/http4sms/send.asp?USER=Steffen&PW=steffen123&RCV=4782123254&TXT=hello&SND=Steffen">
   <button>Send Message</button>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: If that's your actual code, you're missing many essential parts; such as assigning POST/GET variables; I.e.: `$rcv=$_GET['rcv'];` etc.. I'm under the impression you want to use the default GET method. Plus the file's call `send.asp?USER` --- Is that the actual page's extension?

Comment: It's not my entire code, its just the part that I have a problem with. I also have a PHP script to enter the Message, Sender and Receiver into a MYSql DB. I guess I do. I'm kinda new to PHP so I don't know all the functions yet. 
Yes, it's the page's extension. It's a SMS service that allows me to send a SMS from a page, but I want the Message, Sender and Receiver to be a variable

Comment: I don't know enough about ASP to say if they mix or not and even more so, unsure if one can pass a PHP variable to an ASP file. You probably could pull it off with JS and/or sessions.

Comment: Why are you using a `.asp` file? Since you tagged this as `php`, it would be so much simpler going full PHP.

Comment: It is a PHP file, but as I said, I'm kinda new to PHP. But I maybe have a solution, I'll try that and come back if it doesn't work.
Thanks for the help, appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know by adding `@` in front of my name so I get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

change `<form>` to

```
<form method="GET" action="">
```

The get will append the name and value of your fields into the url. You should always use the method and action attributes of the form.

Comment: Omitted form method default's to GET.